# How to determine the JSON data input format for an ASP .NET JSON WebService?

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, rest

I have an ASP.NET WebService that supports standard WSDL based SOAP calls **and** a JSON based POST interface. I did not develop it and am not overly familiar with the technology but I have a client that wishes to use the JSON based service rather that the SOAP service. This may be a long shot however, I am wondering how(if at all possible) can one derive the correct JSON input format that needs to be supplied to the service via the POST data? All I'm armed with is a a working sample of the required SOAP based call.

Regards, F.

Comment: If they're using the built-in JSON deserializer you could try generating a SOAP client proxy, loading up the request structure with your data and then using the built-in JSON serializer to turn it into JSON. However in the general case I'd be surprised if you can guarantee the mapping. If you haven't already fired off an email to whoever did develop the web-service you should. (I'm assuming you don't have the web-service source code either?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really need to get in touch with this guys in order to get the json template you would need to generate.
Then you can use the built in but slow json serializer or use a library like json.net or fastjson.

Using the opportunity, I have developed a little Json Requester library that uses json.net and is prepared to serialize an object into json, create the http request and deserialize the result into an object. When you have the json object template you can give it a try.

https://github.com/ademargomes/JsonRequest